# Listing blobs inside container in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am able to download a single file from azure blob storage using python:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, ContainerClient
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
sas_url = 'https://tenant_datalake.blob.core.windows.net/filename.xml?sp=racwdymeop&st=2022-12-16T14:24:34Z&se=2022-12-16T22:24:34Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=xxxxx'
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob_data.content_as_text())) # works fine
```

However, when I try to list blobs inside a virtual folder after defining an SAS url at virtual folder level, I get

```
# container level 
container_sas_url = 'https://tenantdatalake.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/folder2?sp=racwdlmeop&st=2022-12-16T09:55:06Z&se=2022-12-16T17:55:06Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=d&sig=xxxx&sdd=1'
container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_sas_url)
[*container_client.list_blobs('New')]

HttpResponseError: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
RequestId:3e296e90-101e-00a3-4b5e-1105f9000000
Time:2022-12-16T14:57:54.6144977Z
ErrorCode:InvalidUri
```

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the root folder container rather than a subfolder. There was nothing wrong with the code itself.